# $sort in aggregation framework doesn`t work with two paramethers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I`ve got some problem when i am trying to sort documents.
My query looks like:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'landlords',
  localField: 'landlordIds',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'landlords',
},
{ $unwind: '$landlords' },
{ $sort: { 'landlords.fullName': 1, expiritionDate: 1 } }
```

This code sort result by fullName field, second param don`t apply. Why so ?
The contracts collection [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgL1Y.png)

The landlords [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEpqy.png)

Comment: An example document with all the fields in question would really go a long way.

Comment: @chridam i don`t understand what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some sample documents/data which actually show the `landlords` and `expiritionDate` fields?

Comment: @chridam landlods it is object, fullName has string value and expiration Date is date type

Comment: @chridam by the way separately if pass only expirationDate or 'landlords.fullName' sort works fine. But in this case sort works for fullName only

Comment: What @chridam meant is, if you can add an example of how your collections look like. You are obviously joining the result of one collection to another and it's hard to tell if you don't provide a real example

Comment: @AlexP. maybe you know what is the problem ? I already added collections model in the descriptions

Comment: Hi Yaroslav; images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors